# How to use high resolution images in a way that application don't lag?

Tags: android, photos

High/medium resolution photo takes time to load from drawable and affects application performance, whereas low resolution photo looks blurred; I want to use high resolution images but not compromise with the performance, How to do that?

I am trying to set a *high resolution background image* of layout login from drawable, so when switching between components of the same activity lagging occurs.

For instance: switching between field email to password, keyboard appears/disappear in slow motion.

Comment: You can use some library like picasso to load images asynchronously

Comment: That is a very broad question. You may wish to narrow this down to a more concrete scenario.

Comment: Lots of strategies for that: make sure you load asynchronously (this is the default for most of the following suggestions), load low res first and load higher res later, if this is a zooming application, load the low res and start zoomed out first and start loading the higher res in the background. Try different image compression/decompression techniques.

If you're concerned with run time performance, look to a GPU based solution for rendering.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you , I would use the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. Its faster than [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and ideal when you want to load large images. 
From the github documentation :

> Glide's primary focus is on making scrolling any kind of a list of images as smooth and fast as possible, but Glide is also effective for almost any case where you need to fetch, resize, and display a remote image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Piccaso. It will adjust and load a correct image size depending on your device and size of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what you need, but you can use a FrameLayout to download  multiple pictures in the background and set them invisible till you need it with android:visibility attribute.This solution is for one activity. Asynchronous work and cache can be the answer.
You should consider resize your pic anyway, users prefer see the pic than wait and quit, they know the limitations of their devices (so does android ;-).